# Why is my OR operator not working in python?

Tags: python, while-loop, or-operator

`while scr_1 <= 4   or scr_2 <= 4` :#scr stands for score

The thing happening here is that my `while` loop ends only when BOTH scores have reached 5! I want it to end when only one of the above reaches 5! Please help me.

Comment: To continue the loop, it sounds like you need both conditions to be true. So use `and`, not `or`.

Answer (score 1):

turn your 'or' to an 'and'

the reason for this is because you want the loop to only continue if both scr_1 and scr_2 is less than or equal to 4.